# how to export then import a powerapps solution that has a canvas app using a custom component

Tags: import, export, powerapps, custom-component

I cannot seem to export then import a powerapps solution that has a canvas app that references a custom component. I'm using the powerapps portal to create the solution, where I add the canvas app that uses the custom component. When I export, download, and try to import the solution at this point it fails with the error:

> error code 8004F036: The dependent component CustomControl (Id=xxx) does not exist. Failure trying to associate it with CanvasApp (Id=yyy) as a dependency. Missing dependency lookup type = EntityNameLookup.

If I first go to the solution and click 'add required objects' it will not add the custom component. If I manually add it, it shows it as added, but still after exporting, downloading, and importing, I get the same error. It would be great if someone knows the proper steps to get this working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to do this in 2 steps.

1. custom control (either you created on or you used from some 3 rd party) should be deployed (imported) to Target system. If it is managed solution from 3rd party then you might have solution.zip file use this and deploy to target system. If you created this custom control, then create separate solution and just add your custom control and deploy this solution.
2. Once custom control is imported, then deploy/import your powerapps solutions.

Comment: thanks. I figured that was probably the way to go, so I'm in the middle of trying that approach. Too bad one can't "bundle" solutions together. I will likely accept this as the solution after a bit more testing.